# Find the height of an irregular triangular pyramid given the edge lengths

Tags: geometry

How do you find the height of a triangular pyramid given the lengths of its base sides and slant heights? Given a tetrahedron $ABCD$, I want to find the height from $A$ to triangle $BCD$. $AB = 5$, $AC = 3$, $BC = 4$, $BD = 4$, $AD = 3$, $CD = \frac{12}{5}\sqrt{2}$

Comment: You can find the volume of the tetrahedron (using, say, the [Cayley-Menger determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Volume)) and the area of the base (via [Heron's Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula)). Then recall how volume, area-of-base, and height-to-that-base are related.

Comment: Use the fact that ABC and ABD are right triangles (Pythagoras?)

Comment: The foot of the height does not lie on the midpoint of $CD$ because for that to happen, $BC$ must be perpendicular to $CD$.